# Conditional 'Case When' within 'Where' Clause T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, case, where-clause

I'm trying to use a case when clause in a where statement to return values if they fall into 2 different categories.

This is my code so far:

```
 create view dbo.eightmonthinc
as
select *
from dbo.rentincreaseview 
where 
    case when [days same form] <= 9 
    then datediff(month, leasedate ,'2016-08-01 00:00:00') >= 8
    else datediff(month, rentlastchanged ,'2016-08-01 00:00:00') >= 12)
    end
go
```

Here is a verbal break down of what I am trying to do.

If my days same formula returns a value <= 9 then I want to only return values where the difference between the lease date and a set future date is >=8.

If my days same formula is >9 then I only want to return values where the difference between the rent last changed date and a future date is >=12.

However, I want both sets of data to be returned in the same query. Unfortunately, I keep getting an 'incorrect syntax' error.

I'm still learning, so I'm a little unsure of how to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I fixed a logic error in my answer - please check it out - the old version will produce wrong results. Credit to Gordon Linoff, whose answer pointed out the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a `case` statement like that (evaluating different boolean expressions based on input), but you can rewrite your logic with boolean AND and OR instead:

```
where 
    ([days same form] <= 9 and 
     datediff(month, leasedate ,'2016-08-01 00:00:00') >= 8)
    or 
    ([days same form] > 9 and 
     datediff(month, rentlastchanged ,'2016-08-01 00:00:00') >= 12))
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do what you want as a `case` statement, but it needs to be an argument to `datediff()`:

```
create view dbo.eightmonthinc as
select *
from dbo.rentincreaseview 
where ([days same form] <= 9 and datediff(month, leasedate, '2016-08-01') >= 8
      ) or
      ([days same form] > 9 and datediff(month, rentlastchanged, '2016-08-01') >= 12
      );
```

The correct logic needs to repeat the comparison on `[days same form]` twice.  In addition, you don't need the hh:mm:ss on the date constant.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you were intending to do although you'll probably stick with the accepted answer since that's the more familiar form. Obviously the trick below is to nest `case` expressions. Remember that `case` evaluates to a value, not a conditional, as many people have attempted to do.

```
select *
from dbo.rentincreaseview 
where 
    case when [days same form] <= 9 then
        case
            when datediff(month, leasedate ,'2016-08-01') >= 8 then 1
            when datediff(month, rentlastchanged ,'2016-08-01') >= 12) then 1
        end
    end
go
```

And as was also hinted at by Gordon you could try:

```
...
where
    datediff(
        month,
        case when [days same form] then leasedate else rentlastchanged end,
        '2016-08-01 00:00:00'
    ) 
      >=
    case when [days same form] <= 9 then 8 else 12 end
```

There are some cases where these forms could prove useful. Most of the time I doubt it's a good idea.